# The Tagify dropdown with suggestions works in JS but not in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, tagify

I am using Tagify to allow the user to indicate or select tags for the publication of an article.

In addition to typing in tags, I need to list some suggestions that are already in the database.
At the moment I have not used Ajax because I am doing some tests to see how it should actually work. Nevertheless, the same plug-in works in JS but not in jQuery. The code snippet for opening the dropdown does not work in jQuery.

Where am I going wrong?

**JS**

```
var tagify = new Tagify(document.getElementById('app-tag-input'), {whitelist: []});
tagify.on('input', onInput);

function onInput(e) {

   var value = e.detail.value;
   tagify.whitelist = null;
   tagify.loading(true).dropdown.hide(); 
   tagify.whitelist = [{id: 1, value: 'html'}, {id: 2, value: 'css'}];
   tagify.loading(false).dropdown.show(value);

}
```

**jQuery**

```
var tagify = $('input[name="tag"]').tagify({whitelist: []});

tagify.on('input', onInput);

function onInput(e, tagName) {

   var value = tagName.value;
   tagify.whitelist = null;
   tagify.data('tagify').loading(true).dropdown.hide();
   tagify.whitelist = [{id: 1, value: 'html'}, {id: 2, value: 'css'}];
   tagify.data('tagify').loading(false).dropdown.show(value);

}
```

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" name="tag" id="app-tag-input">
```

Comment: Please include your HTML, ideally in a snippet with all the relevant `<script` so that it runs, even if it doesn't "work".   Your first code uses the equivalent of `$("#app-tag-input").tagify` while the second is not the same, using `name=tag`.  Without HTML, we can't see if you actually have that element.  But **always test your selectors** - ie `console.log($('input[name="tag"]').length);`

Comment: I have added the tag input field.
The field is detected, I display it on the screen and using the JS snippet also shows the dropdown.

Comment: Here is a test link: https://jsfiddle.net/f549m76g/

Comment: As far I can see, your fiddle (jquery) works exactly the same as [this filddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hv4bzrpn/) (your javascript version)

Comment: Both using Firefox and using Chrome, the jQuery snippet does not show the dropdown. The JS snippet, on the other hand, does show it.

Comment: Does it show it in the fiddle I provided above? https://jsfiddle.net/hv4bzrpn/  Because it doesn't for me.   Can you provide a link/fiddle that does "show the dropdown"?

Comment: If you type 'html' or 'css', the drop-down menu opens. (https://jsfiddle.net/hv4bzrpn/)

Comment: Now that I know what I'm looking for, easy fix:  https://jsfiddle.net/xoap1knt/   your jquery version uses `tagify.data('tagify')` to set loading/etc and needs to do the same for the `.whitelist()` call.

Answer (score 0):

In the jquery version, to access tagify properties you need to use:

```
tagify.data('tagify').
```

this also applies to the `tagify.whitelist =` call:

```
tagify.data('tagify').whitelist =
```

which was missing from the jquery version.

Updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/xoap1knt/

Updated code: Unfortunately, a snippet doesn't work in SO as it appears tagify uses localStorage for some unknown reason.

```js
$(function () {
  var tagify = $('input[name="tag"]').tagify({whitelist: []});
  tagify.on('input', onInput);
  function onInput(e, tagName) {
    var value = tagName.value;
    tagify.whitelist = null;
    tagify.data('tagify').loading(true).dropdown.hide();
    tagify.data('tagify').whitelist = [{id: 1, value: 'html'}, {id: 2, value: 'css'}];
    tagify.data('tagify').loading(false).dropdown.show(value);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tagify/4.16.4/jQuery.tagify.min.js'></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tagify/4.16.4/tagify.min.css" />
<form action="save.php">
  <fieldset>
    <input type="text" name="tag">
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you very much! Unfortunately, it was not specified in the documentation.